# Dll size differs for build on different PC

Tags: visual-c++, dll, size

I have a VC++ dll library which is built (with Visual Studio 2003) on Windows XP machines ( a US-English PC and a German PC). The source code is the same and does not have any language specific code. The Release version of the dll built on the German PC is approx 30 MB whereas the dll built on the US-English PC is approx 7 MB.

What could be the reason for this? Is this normal?

Comment: Tag `german` removed as part of the [**2012 cleanup**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a lot of information to go on. If I were to take a guess, maybe you are static linking a different set of libs perhaps.

Use ["dumpbin"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c%28VS.71%29.aspx) on both dlls and see what is different.

Comment: I have copied the complete folder structure (with the solution and project files) and recompile them on the other PC. 

There is no difference in the project or sources.

Comment: There are a lot more files used in generating your exe. These are included as part of the VC++ development environment. What is most likely the cause of your bloat is that these extra libraries are international versions and contain additional resources for different locales. If these were being statically linked, the final exe would be bigger. Again, the dumpbin util should indicate this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one machine is configured to produce a debug build.